# Как убрать черной фон у товара Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить ошибку.

При переносе сайта с локальки на хостинг, с помощью резервной копии restore.php. После успешного завершения. Заметил на сайте следующую ошибку, при просмотре товара через "режим правки", вкладке "Подробно" добавляется черный фон к фотографий товара, в анонсе также выводится черный фон. 
В публичной части выводится, черной фон только на странице корзины. Только вот это ошибка на сайте, остальное проверял все работает.

На веб-окружении все работает. Думал может быть есть какая-то разница между хостингом и веб-окружением, позвонил в тех.поддержку хостинга, отправил свои настройки php, все сходятся говорят.

Проверял на разных браузерах тоже самые. Mozilla, Chrome.

Прикрепляю 3 скриншота

1) Как выглядит фото товара через "режим правки" вкладка "Подробно"

2) Как выглядит фото товара на отдельной странице

3) Как выглядит фото товара на станице корзины

Пробовал заново удалять и добавлять фото, не помогает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто предположение, возможно, на вашем хостинге, в отличии от локалки не установлены GD или Imagick. Или установлены не те версии что на локалке. Когда то с таким сталкивался, не с битриксом, к сожалению, но проблема была в какой то из этих либ. Не помню, правда, в какой именно и какая :)

Answer (score 1):

Чёрный фон на анонсах возникает из-за того, что Битрикс при создании миниатюры применяет фильтр "Резкость".

Он по умолчанию включен в методе CFile::ResizeImageGet и равен 15%

Избежать этого можно сгенерировав миниатюры самому с отключенным фильтром.

Пример получения изображения без чёрного фона:

```
$size = array('width'=>150, 'height'=>150);
$filters = array(
    array("name" => "sharpen", "precision" => 0)
);
$file = CFile::ResizeImageGet($imageId, $size, BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, true, $filters);
```

Подробнее о методе в документации:

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/resizeimageget.php